# Will supervisor gracefully restart all of the queue workers if supervisorctl reload / restart?

Tags: laravel, supervisord

When this command `php artisan queue:restart` run, all of the queue workers are gracefully restarted.

But, if these commands `supervisorctl reload` or `supervisorctl restart` run, what the commands run behind? Will they kill the queue workers forcefully and start the workers again?

Sometimes, when the supervisor config is changed, supervisor need to reload and restart.

If supervisor does not start the queue workers gracefully, any workaround so that it won't kill the workers forcefully, so that I do not need to do some cleanup?

Comment: Do you have a supervisor configuration setup to run `php artisan queue:work`?

Comment: yes, mostly I'll change the `numprocs` so I need to reload and restart the supervisor.

Comment: Okay, it will restart all the queue workers then. You can verify this by running `ps aux | grep queue` from the terminal and seeing the processes running.

Comment: What was the solution for this? I am wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Using Supervisor reload or restart command as of **Laravel 5.4+** will instruct the queue worker to do a graceful shutdown.

But, make sure your supervisor does not kill the worker before the worker attempts to graceful shutdown by setting "*stopwaitsecs*" in your supervisor config file to a value higher than the estimated job processing time.